# The textfields and label are not getting placed over the image

Tags: html, css

There is two file one is html and css
The first page contain the button to open a modal.
I want to place a background image in modal but my contents are getting down while placing the back ground image.
I want to place my all contents above the modal back ground image. 
Can u please see it

```css
<style>
       
        /* Hidden by default */
        
        .ab{
            text-align: center;
        }
        h2{
            text-align: center;
           padding-top: 200px;
        }
        button{
            width: 300px;
            height: 40px;
        }
        
        /* Seting The Log-in Modal */
        
        .my_modal{
            display: none;      /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed;    /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1;         /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;        /* Full width */
            height: 100%;       /* Full height */
            overflow: auto;     /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0);  /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }
        .modal-animated{
            height: 100%;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: #fefefe;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            margin:5% auto 15% auto;   /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
        }
        .backg{
            <image
        }
        
        /* Login- close button */
        
        
        .close{
            position: absolute;
            right: 25px;
            top: 0;
            color: aqua;
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .close:hover,
        .close:focus{
             color: red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        /* setting login image background & resizing vatar */
        
        
        .img-container{
            background-image: url(http://artatm.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/wallpaper_182372.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            height: 300px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        img.avatar{
            width: 40%;
            border-radius: 60%;
        }
        input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .container{
            padding: 16px;
        }
        button[type="submit"]{
             width: 50vw;
             height: 3vw;
             position: absolute;
             left: 49vw;
             top: 110vh;
             transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
             font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
             font-size: 2vw;
             letter-spacing: 0.1em;
             color: #e8e8e8;
             border: none;
             border-radius: 10px;
             outline: none;
             background: linear-gradient(45deg, #4CAF50, teal, #4CAF50);
             background-size: 400% 400%;
             box-shadow: 1vw 1vw 0 green;
             cursor: pointer;
             transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }
        button[type="submit"]:hover {
            animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
            font-size: 2.05vw;
            box-shadow: 0.2vw 0.2vw 0 lightcoral;
        }

        @keyframes gradient {
        50% {
            background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
    </style>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
        <div class="ab">
            <h2>Hello!!!</h2>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
            <button  onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Register</button>
        </div>
        
        <div id= "id01" class="my_modal">
        
        <form class="modal-animated animate" action="actionpahe.php">
        <div class="img-container">
             <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            <img src="avatar-05.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            
        </div>
        <div class="contents">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type= "text" placeholder="Enter User_name" name= "uname" required>
            
            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type= "password" placeholder="Enter Pass_code" name="pwd" required>
            
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Remember Me
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

You Can run the output here to see the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's will help you :

```css
<style>
       
        /* Hidden by default */
        
        .ab{
            text-align: center;
        }
        h2{
            text-align: center;
           padding-top: 200px;
        }
        button{
            width: 300px;
            height: 40px;
        }
        
        /* Seting The Log-in Modal */
        
        .my_modal{
            display: none;      /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed;    /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1;         /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;        /* Full width */
            height: 100%;       /* Full height */
            overflow: auto;     /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0);  /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }
        .modal-animated{
            background-image: url(http://artatm.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/wallpaper_182372.jpg);
            height: 100%;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: #fefefe;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            margin:5% auto 15% auto;   /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
        }
        .backg{
            <image
        }
        
        /* Login- close button */
        
        
        .close{
            position: absolute;
            right: 25px;
            top: 0;
            color: aqua;
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .close:hover,
        .close:focus{
             color: red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        /* setting login image background & resizing vatar */
        
        
        .img-container{                
            background-size: cover;
            height: 300px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        img.avatar{
            width: 40%;
            border-radius: 60%;
        }
        input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        input[type="text"]{
            display: block;
        }
        .container{
            padding: 16px;
        }
        button[type="submit"]{
             width: 50vw;
             height: 3vw;
             display: block;
             font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
             font-size: 2vw;
             letter-spacing: 0.1em;
             color: #e8e8e8;
             border: none;
             border-radius: 10px;
             outline: none;
             background: linear-gradient(45deg, #4CAF50, teal, #4CAF50);
             background-size: 400% 400%;
             box-shadow: 1vw 1vw 0 green;
             cursor: pointer;
             transition: all 0.3s ease;
             margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        button[type="submit"]:hover {
            animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
            font-size: 2.05vw;
            box-shadow: 0.2vw 0.2vw 0 lightcoral;
        }

        @keyframes gradient {
        50% {
            background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
    </style>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
        <div class="ab">
            <h2>Hello!!!</h2>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
            <button  onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Register</button>
        </div>
        
        <div id= "id01" class="my_modal">
        
        <form class="modal-animated animate" action="actionpahe.php">
        <div class="img-container">
             <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            <img src="avatar-05.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            
        
        <div class="contents">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type= "text" placeholder="Enter User_name" name= "uname" required>
            
            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type= "password" placeholder="Enter Pass_code" name="pwd" required>
            
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Remember Me
        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `position: relative;` to move it around ***REALLY*** easily. Your CSS code where you style the inputs would look like this,

```css
<style>
       
        /* Hidden by default */
        
        .ab{
            text-align: center;
        }
        h2{
            text-align: center;
           padding-top: 200px;
        }
        button{
            width: 300px;
            height: 40px;
        }
        
        /* Seting The Log-in Modal */
        
        .my_modal{
            display: none;      /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed;    /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1;         /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;        /* Full width */
            height: 100%;       /* Full height */
            overflow: auto;     /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0);  /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }
        .modal-animated{
            height: 100%;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: #fefefe;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            margin:5% auto 15% auto;   /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
        }
        .backg{
            <image
        }
        
        /* Login- close button */
        
        
        .close{
            position: absolute;
            right: 25px;
            top: 0;
            color: aqua;
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .close:hover,
        .close:focus{
             color: red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        /* setting login image background & resizing vatar */
        
        
        .img-container{
            background-image: url(http://artatm.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/wallpaper_182372.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            height: 300px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        img.avatar{
            width: 40%;
            border-radius: 60%;
        }
        input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-sizing: border-box;

            position: relative;
            top: -210px;
        }

        label{
            position: relative;
            top: -215px;
            color: white;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        .container{
            padding: 16px;
        }
        button[type="submit"]{
             width: 50vw;
             height: 3vw;
             position: absolute;
             left: 49vw;
             top: 110vh;
             transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
             font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
             font-size: 2vw;
             letter-spacing: 0.1em;
             color: #e8e8e8;
             border: none;
             border-radius: 10px;
             outline: none;
             background: linear-gradient(45deg, #4CAF50, teal, #4CAF50);
             background-size: 400% 400%;
             box-shadow: 1vw 1vw 0 green;
             cursor: pointer;
             transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }
        button[type="submit"]:hover {
            animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
            font-size: 2.05vw;
            box-shadow: 0.2vw 0.2vw 0 lightcoral;
        }

        @keyframes gradient {
        50% {
            background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
    </style>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
        <div class="ab">
            <h2>Hello!!!</h2>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
            <button  onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Register</button>
        </div>
        
        <div id= "id01" class="my_modal">
        
        <form class="modal-animated animate" action="actionpahe.php">
        <div class="img-container">
             <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            <img src="avatar-05.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            
        </div>
        <div class="contents">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type= "text" placeholder="Enter User_name" name= "uname" required>
            
            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type= "password" placeholder="Enter Pass_code" name="pwd" required>
            
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Remember Me
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this works. If you run the snippet, you will see that the images and labels are over the image. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Here, I am putting a `relative` position to the labels and text and password inputs. The relative positioning in CSS allows you to easily move around objects using the `top: ;`, `bottom: ;`, `left: ;` and `right: ;` parametres.

Comment: Relative means that the `px` that you are passing will move your object away from the container it is in, not from the borders of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
   /* Hidden by default */
   .ab{
   text-align: center;
   }
   h2{
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 200px;
   }
   button{
   width: 300px;
   height: 40px;
   }
   /* Seting The Log-in Modal */
   .my_modal{
   display: none;      /* Hidden by default */
   position: fixed;    /* Stay in place */
   z-index: 1;         /* Sit on top */
   padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;        /* Full width */
   height: 100%;       /* Full height */
   overflow: auto;     /* Enable scroll if needed */
   background-color: rgb(0,0,0);  /* Fallback color */
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
   }
   .modal-animated{
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   background-color: #fefefe;
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #888;
   margin:5% auto 15% auto;   /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
   }
   .backg{
   <image
   }
   /* Login- close button */
   .close{
   position: absolute;
   right: 25px;
   top: 0;
   color: aqua;
   font-size: 35px;
   font-weight: bold;
   }
   .close:hover,
   .close:focus{
   color: red;
   cursor: pointer;
   }
   /* setting login image background & resizing vatar */
   #id01{
   background-image: url(http://artatm.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/wallpaper_182372.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   height: 300px;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
   position: relative;
   width:900px;
   position: absolute;
   }
   img.avatar{
   width: 40%;
   border-radius: 60%;
   }
   input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
   width: 100%;
   padding: 12px 20px;
   margin: 8px 0;
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   .container{
   padding: 16px;
   }
   button[type="submit"]{
   width: 50vw;
   height: 3vw;
   position: absolute;
   left: 49vw;
   top: 110vh;
   transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
   font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
   font-size: 2vw;
   letter-spacing: 0.1em;
   color: #e8e8e8;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 10px;
   outline: none;
   background: linear-gradient(45deg, #4CAF50, teal, #4CAF50);
   background-size: 400% 400%;
   box-shadow: 1vw 1vw 0 green;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
   }
   button[type="submit"]:hover {
   animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
   font-size: 2.05vw;
   box-shadow: 0.2vw 0.2vw 0 lightcoral;
   }
   @keyframes gradient {
   50% {
   background-position: 100% 0;
   }
   }
</style>
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="ab">
         <h2>Hello!!!</h2>
         <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
         <button  onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Register</button>
      </div>
      <div id= "id01" class="my_modal">
         <form class="modal-animated animate" action="actionpahe.php">
            <div class="img-container">
               <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="contents">
               <label><b>Username</b></label>
               <input type= "text" placeholder="Enter User_name" name= "uname" required>
               <label><b>Password</b></label>
               <input type= "password" placeholder="Enter Pass_code" name="pwd" required>
               <button type="submit">Login</button>
               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Remember Me
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.